# How to show $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\Vert{\vec{a}+\vec{b}\Vert^2}-\Vert{\vec{a}-\vec{b}\Vert^2}\right)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

The Homework Exercise I am working on, is:

> Let $\overrightarrow{a}, \overrightarrow{b}$ be vectors. Show that
>    $\overrightarrow{a} \cdot
>  \overrightarrow{b}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\Vert{\overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b}\Vert^2}-\Vert{\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b}\Vert^2}\right)$.

Things I tried:

1. Using the property $\Vert \overrightarrow{u}\Vert^2=\overrightarrow{u} \cdot \overrightarrow{u}$, I tried to make $\Vert{\overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b}\Vert^2} =\left(\overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b} \right) \cdot \left(\overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b} \right)$ and $\Vert{\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b}\Vert^2} =\left(\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b} \right) \cdot \left(\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b} \right)$

I'm not sure if that was a correct step, but then I substituted into the main equation to get 
$$
\overrightarrow{a} \cdot
 \overrightarrow{b}
 = \frac{1}{4}\left(
(\overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b} ) \cdot (\overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b} )
- (\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b} ) \cdot 
(\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b} ) 
\right)
$$

Am not sure where to go from here, or if I'm even heading in the right direction...

Comment: Next use the distributive property of the dot product over vector addition, and collect like terms.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity

Comment: The proposed duplicate focuses on *discovery* of the polarization identity (or identities, if complex normed vector spaces are included), so it doesn't make an ideal duplicate.  There are previous Questions with much the same focus as this one, but the Answers given there are in most cases less detailed than the calculation already provided in the problem statement here.  So I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that $$\vec a\cdot (\vec b + \vec c) = \vec a \cdot \vec b + \vec a\cdot \vec c$$

and write it all out. A lot of things should cancel out.

Answer (score 0):

Just expand the dot products by didtributivity in the right-hand side:
\begin{align}
(\vec a+\vec b)\cdot(\vec a+\vec b)-(\vec a-\vec b)\cdot(\vec a-\vec b)&=\begin{aligned}[t]\vec a\cdot\vec a&+\vec a\cdot\vec b+\vec b\cdot\vec a+\vec b\cdot\vec b\\
&-\vec a\cdot\vec a+\vec a\cdot\vec b+\vec b\cdot\vec a-\vec b\cdot\vec b
\end{aligned}\\
&=2\vec a\cdot\vec b+2\vec b\cdot\vec a=4\vec a\cdot\vec b
\end{align}